# Adaptation of this proof of spectral theorem to the complex case

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

My question is quite simple, I would like to know why we can't use this proof to the complex case, i.e., the operator $T$ is self adjoint on a complex n-dimensional inner product space $V$.

Can we adapt this proof to the complex case?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the real $n$-dimensional inner product space is even dimensional and if its Nijenhuis tensor vanishes, then the space is a complex space. Just saying (I don't know if it's helpful), since once I saw "real" and "adaptation to complex", I remembered the Nijenhuis tensor.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why not. The proof should be the same...the only words that must change is symmetric to self-adjoint, and real to complex in the statement of the theorem, but the proof should be the same using the standard inner product for complex vector spaces.

The matrix version you probably know is

> Every Hermitian matrix is unitarily similar to a real diagonal matrix.

and it's easy to prove using Schur's theorem.

Now just an example of a matrix that is complex and symmetric, but not diagonalizable (just for kicks): \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix}1&i\\i&-1 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation}
It has characteristic polynomial $x^2$, and so it's minimum polynomial must also be $x^2$. This means that this matrix is not diagonalizable, and has Jordan normal form \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation} So clearly the theorem is not directly applicable to operators over the complex field.

Comment: Thank you for the example, very important!

Comment: So what is called spectral theorem? the matrix version you wrote or the operator version I wrote?

Comment: I am not familiar with this theorem being called the "spectral theorem" on it's own. I guess different sources refer to it in different ways, the spectral theorem as I know it lists a number of results that are true for a linear operator in general (of which square matrices can be seen as a special case when left multiplying), when the operator is self-adjoint over the real numbers or normal over complex field (so in the complex case you can in fact replace self-adjoint with normal). The term spectral is of course a reference to the eigenvalues of an operator.

Comment: so just to further clarify, the spectral theorem as i know it, lists 5 results: (a) decomposition of $V$ into a direct sum of eigenspaces (b) The eigenspaces are pairwise orthogonal. (c) $T_iT_j=\delta_{ij}T_i$ where each $T_i$ is the orthogonal projection of $V$ onto eigenspace $W_i$ (d) $I=\sum_i T_i$ (e) $T= \sum_i \lambda_iT_i$.

Comment: here is a very good article btw - http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2313117?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103773878741

Comment: But these 5 results are equivalent to $V$ be diagonalizable, right?

Comment: that $T$ is orthogonally/unitarily diagonalizable is the essence of it, yes